# Creating a new map using key value pairs, not saving

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, dart

Im decoding a json and transforming it in a variable of type map [string , List < LatLng>] and trying to retun it as the code of this function, howevwer im unable to save it as a map in the variable _polyFinal:

```
       static getPoligoni() async {
http.Response _response = await http.get('$api/posizione/poligoni',
    headers: {'Authorization': '${dataController.tokenBearer.value}'});
if (_response.statusCode == 200) {
  Map<String, dynamic> _json = jsonDecode(_response.body);
  var _poly = Map.from(_json["Poligoni"]).map(
    (k, v) {
      return MapEntry<String, List<String>>(
        k,
        List<String>.from(
          v.map((x) => x),
        ),
      );
    },
  );
  List<String> _verticiRaw;
  List<LatLng> _vertici = [];
  Map<String, List<LatLng>> _polyFinal = {};
  for (String key in _poly.keys) {
    // print(_verticiRaw);
    _verticiRaw?.clear();
    _verticiRaw = _poly[key];
    for (int i = 0; i < _verticiRaw.length; i++) {
      print(i);
      var _posVirgola = _verticiRaw[i].indexOf(',');
      String posx, posy;
      posx = _verticiRaw[i].substring(0, _posVirgola);
      posy = _verticiRaw[i].substring(_posVirgola + 1);
      var lat = double.tryParse(posx);
      var lon = double.tryParse(posy);
      _vertici.add(LatLng(lat, lon));
    }
    print(key);
    print(_vertici);
    _polyFinal.putIfAbsent(key, () => _vertici);
    _vertici?.clear();
  }
  dataController.showLoadingStatus(false);
  // print(_polyFinal);
  // return _polyFinal;
```

If I try to print the polyFinal variable at the end of the cycle i get an empty map, And if I print the variable during the cycle every key-value pair get transformed in the following

key --> last vertici value

I tried to chek the values of both key and vertici and they are different every time the cycle is run.

Any help understanding this behavior is greatly appreciated,
Best Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved by putting

```
 _polyFinal.putIfAbsent(key, () => _vertici.toList());
```

Maybe _vertici is just a pointer and not the value itself.